# What is the lowest priority Process Explorer can set?

Tags: windows, process-explorer, priority

I ask because the last two entries in the context menu sound as if they may be in the wrong order:

- …
- `Background: 4 (Low I/O and Memory Priority)`
- `Idle: 4`

If these both have the same numeric base priority, but `Background` has other lower settings, is it not effectively the lower of the two?

(I checked the Process Explorer help, but found no details of their meaning.)
([What is Windows Priority and Affinity and what advatanges does it provide?](https://superuser.com/questions/181577/what-is-windows-priority-and-affinity-and-what-advatanges-does-it-provide) refers to an older version of the context menu without these entries.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Background" has the same process priority as Idle, but also assigns the process low I/O and memory priorities, further reducing its impact on your system.

Above [Paraphrased from/More info here](http://betanews.com/2012/02/17/process-explorer-15-13-adds-background-priority-setting/)

Related article from Microsoft's MSDN about the ["SetThreadPriority function"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686277(v=vs.85).aspx):

> Begin **background** processing mode. The system lowers the resource scheduling priorities of the thread so that it can perform background work without significantly affecting activity in the foreground.

Comment: Thanks, that seems clear enough — so they **are** in the ‘wrong’ order in the context menu. But a minor query: is it not actually `SetPriorityClass`, i.e. process rather than thread priority, that you mean?